# am I doing something wrong in writing or downloading anything

Tags: visual-studio-code, mingw

Hi guys I just started to learn code and this is my first day today I downloded  VS code and mingw as a compiler but i dont know why I am getting "Access is denied." after compling my code.

[image]

Comment: at the end of your command line, can you try moving the " *after* Untitled-1?

Comment: I'm not sure the quote placement in "*c:\Users\stuff\"untitled-1* is valid. I'm also not familiar enough with Visual Studio Code to tell you which configuration file needs correcting.

Comment: Try running each of the 3 commands by hand in a command prompt -  `&&` is the command separator and should not be included in the command.  Report back which is failing.

Comment: Note: Visual Studio Code takes a bit of work to configure correctly. If you need to learn the ins-and-outs of Visual Studio Code AND C++ at the same time, you might want to start with the simpler-to-install-and-configure [Visual Studio Community edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/). This will reduce most of the concerns about "Did I goof up my code or did I not set the build tools up correctly?" Once you have more experience you'll be able to easily tell *mistake in code* from *mistake in configuration* and the harder-to-configure tools become a more attractive option.